# How do I get jQuery autocomplete to show anchor tags?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How do I get jQuery autocomplete to show <a> tags?

I'm using jQuery autocommit to search names. I would like the dropdown returned from the Server to include HTML, specifically <a> tags, so I can return the name and the email and the company each within an <a> tag.

Currently, the HTML that I return from the server is displayed in the autcommit dropdown as text and doesn't act as HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this, and see if it helps: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-html-in-autocomplete

Comment: thank you. The difficulty with that solution is the parsing of the server data by the jQuery. I can't seem to get it working. I appreciate your help